# Inserting into a C# List of Objects that uses a Property of the Object to Sort

Tags: c#, list, sorting, object, orm

There's a list of objects, each object representing a record from a database. To sort the records there is a property called SortOrder. Here's a sample object:

```
public class GroupInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public GroupInfo()
        {
            Id = 0;
            Text = string.Empty;
            SortOrder = 1;
        }
}
```

A list object would look like this:

```
var list = new List<GroupInfo>();
```

I need to be able to change the SortOrder and update the SortOrder on the other objects in the list. I figured out how to sort up or down by one. I need to know how to change it by more than one and adjust the SortOrder on the other records. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop? Maybe I misunderstand the problem.

Comment: So when you change the sort order on one groupInfo it will change the sort order on the other groupinfos?

Comment: It needs to be able to change the sort on the other groupinfos

Comment: How are you currently trying to update your SortOrder?

Comment: Easily done with linq, will post an example in a minute when the wife gets off the pc!

Comment: Your wife needs to hurry up. ;-)

Comment: Do you need to keep the `SortOrder` in the `GroupInfo` object, and what determines the `SortOrder`? Personally, I would seriously consider solving this with for example a `SortedList<int, GroupInfo>`.   It would still require some logic for updating the `SortOrder`, but you would at least remove some of the complexity from the `GroupInfo` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by first getting the original `SortOrder` and the updated `SortOrder`.  You would then iterate through your collection and adjust the `SortOrder` of any other `GroupInfo` objects that fall inside the range between `original` and `updated`.  you could put all of this in a "SetSortOrder" function that takes in the containing collection.

```
public static void SetSortOrder(List<GroupInfo> groupInfos, GroupInfo target, int newSortOrder)
{
    if (newSortOrder == target.SortOrder)
    {
        return; // No change
    }
    // If newSortOrder > SortOrder, shift all GroupInfos in that range down
    // Otherwise, shift them up
    int sortOrderAdjustment = (newSortOrder > target.SortOrder ? -1 : 1);
    // Get the range of SortOrders that must be updated
    int bottom = Math.Min(newSortOrder, target.SortOrder);
    int top = Math.Max(newSortOrder, target.SortOrder);
    // Get the GroupInfos that fall within our range
    var groupInfosToUpdate = from g in groupInfos
                                where g.Id != target.Id
                                && g.SortOrder >= bottom
                                && g.SortOrder <= top
                                select g;
    // Do the updates
    foreach (GroupInfo g in groupInfosToUpdate)
    {
        g.SortOrder += sortOrderAdjustment;
    }

    target.SortOrder = newSortOrder;
    // Uncomment this if you want the list to resort every time you update
    // one of its members (not a good idea if you're doing bulk changes)
    //groupInfos.Sort((info1, info2) => info1.SortOrder.CompareTo(info2.SortOrder));
}
```

**Update:** As suggested, I moved the logic into a static helper function.

Comment: The problem with this is that you will be passing in the list into a method of an object contained in that list.  I would rather have this method defined outside of GroupInfo.  You could either have it as a helper method in your current scope or you could inherit from List<GroupInfo> and include it there as a method on your collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(item => item.SortOrder);
```

Edit:  Sorry, I misunderstood.  You will need to write yourself a method outside of `GroupInfo` to handle the updating of that property.